# Publishing .Net Core Blazor Web Assembly Client-Server Project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I have developed the Blazor Client Server Web Assembly project using dot Net Core 8.0 using C# and found running successfully on the server by push the published files but did not find any .razor pages there in published directory. I mean either components from server project and pages directory from web assembly client project. how to include these pages in published directory to update frequent page level changes in the future?

I have tried different configuration changes in solution file but it did not work.

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) . See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your specific issue. We know nothing about your code or what you've been doing, other than the fairly vague and unspecific details you've provided so far.

Comment: When you build or publish a site the Razor files are all compiled by the Razor compiler into C# files that are then compiled into to site DLL. You don't change Razor files on the fly in the published site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the solution file. You could using following settings `.csproj` file to copy folder when publish.

server.csproj

```
    <Target Name="CopyComponents" BeforeTargets="Publish">
        <ItemGroup>
            <MyFiles Include="Components\**" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Components\%(RecursiveDir)\" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CopyPages" BeforeTargets="Publish">
        <ItemGroup>
            <MyFiles2 Include="..\BlazorApp28.Client\Pages\**" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles2)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Pages" />
    </Target>
```

Explaination: using `..\BlazorApp28.Client` to reference client project in server.csproj

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, could publish server pages but client web assembly pages did not publish, should I update actual physical DestinationFolder path by replace with $(PublishDir)\Pages ?  I am publishing server only, should I publish client (webassembly) project as well?

Comment: @Manoj Sorry, you need to only publish the server project. I have modified the answer to add configuration to only server.csproj

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. how to publish client web assembly pages in this case when pages are in client project, It will be easy for frequent page level changes in future. need to release the project in the next week.

Comment: @Manoj I mean the new configuration in server.csproj will let you copy both client and server pages.   You could have a try.

Comment: Yes, got it, Thanks for all your support here, just struggling and finding to update client pages if any html change on it and publish. will check, Thank you so much for your help.